# Operation Research penalty function and KKT

Tags: operations-research, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have a problem as this. Wish someone could help me! Thanks a lot!
[image]

Comment: What have you done to solve the problem? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have got the penalty function as $$
p_a\left( \mathbf{x} \right) =x_{1}^{2}-x_1x_2+\frac{3}{2}x_{2}^{2}+3x_1-9x_2+\alpha \left[ \left( \max \left\{ 1-x_1,0 \right\} \right) ^2+\max \left\{ -x_2,0 \right\} ^2 \right] 
$$
And i have got the KKT:$$
\begin{cases}
 2x_1-x_2+3-\lambda _1=0\\
 -x_1+3x_2-9-\lambda _2=0\\
 \lambda _1\left( x_1-1 \right) =0\\
 \lambda _2x_2=0\\
 \lambda _1,\lambda _2\geqslant 0\\
\end{cases}
$$ But i can't write down an estimate of λα, the optimal multiplier vector corresponding to xα

Comment: @Marcus Ritt Could you help me?

Comment: Continue with [part b](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/operation-research-penalty-function-kkt-consider-nlp-min-c-write-estimate-optimal-multipli-q22051507).